# MIT App Inventor 2 aiStarter error?

Tags: android, app-inventor, usb-debugging

When running aiStarter, I receive the following error:

```
Bottle server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8004/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

Shutdown...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 129, in <module>
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 2389, in run
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/bottle", line 2086, in run
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 144, in make_server
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 408, in __init__
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/wsgiref.simple_server", line 48, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/BaseHTTPServer", line 108, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/SocketServer", line 419, in server_bind
  File "/Users/jis/appinventor-setup/MacOS/aiStarter/build/pyi.darwin/aiStarter/out00-PYZ.pyz/socket", line 224, in meth
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
Killed adb
No matching processes belonging to you were found
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Killed emulator
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

I am trying to USB debug but aiStarter cannot find my device. The app inventor knows when aiStarter is running, but cannot see my tablet.

Yes I have USB debugging enabled, and I have never had this problem until now. I am using OSX.

Comment: It says that the *address is already in use*, so you seem to be wanting to start something that is already started, or you have some other process in the same port. I'd try a restart; if that doesn't help, you might want to do a [search in the App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mitappinventortest/address$20already$20in$20use) or ask there

Answer (score 1):

This error is *usually* caused by two processes using the same port trying to connect to your Android device.

---

## Cause

You are likely having multiple instances of aiStarter trying to use the default port to access your device. Make sure to remove all background ones. background.

## Solutions

- Locate the other aiStarter process(es), and stop them.
- Reinstall aiStarter
- Use another Mac/Android device